# DataTable.Copy() or DeepClone. Which one to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, clone

I have a confusion

**Scenario:**

I want to create a copy of a DataTable to be added to another DataSet. There are 2 ways to do it (AFAIK):

```
1. Make a Copy using DataTable.Copy()
2. Make a Deep Clone using 

public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");

    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        return default(T);

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

**My Confusions:**

1. Are there any other ways to do it?
2. Which one is better and why?
3. Does `DataTable.Copy()` internally uses `DeepClone` or some other
   logic?

Comment: Why don't you just merge one to another? I thought merge was the way to do this. Am I missing something in your question? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984388(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: actually i want to creat a dataset copy with selective datatables.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: he mentions `Copy` not `Clone`

Comment: Maybe it's better to use LINQ-To-DataSet and `CopyToDataTable` to filter your `DataSet`. But then we need more informations. @CuongLe: I just saw , thanks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: But `CopyToDataTable` is exception prone when there is no datarow to be copied to datatable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: why dont u use Tims method with a null check before copying?

Comment: @naveen: Please an example will be helpful?

Comment: I am not sure why you need to copy to be able to merge the data? I have a routine that can merge `DataTable`s together, if you feel this is relevent I am happy to post it as an answer. :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something trivial, why can't you do something like

```
DataSet source = GetMySourceDataSet();
DataSet destination = new DataSet();

DataTable orders = source.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

// Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed  
// after August 8, 2001.
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable modifiedOrders = query.IsAny() ? query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>() : new DataTable();
destination.Tables.Add(modifiedOrders);
```

Small helper

```
public static class Utils {
    public static bool IsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) {
        return data != null && data.Any();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**DataTable.Copy()** itself creates a deep copy of the datatable, I am not talking about the implementation of DataTable.Copy() but the way copied data table works it is same as if the data is copied using **DeepClone** i.e. changes made to the data of one table does not affect the other.

So in your case you can simply use :-

```
DataTable dtCopy = dt.Copy();
```

OR you can also use :-

```
DataTable dtCopy = dt.Clone();
dtCopy.Merge(dt);
```